# null Error on Build Log when trying to open project settings

Tags: android, android-studio, nullpointerexception

I'm trying to open settings of the a project that someone left me in the company. When I click on Open Settings the Android Studio IDE fails and show a "null" error.

What I can do?? It says to me to "disabe android support plugin". I'm lost.

```
null
java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at java.lang.Exception.<init>(Exception.java:54)
    at java.lang.RuntimeException.<init>(RuntimeException.java:51)
    at java.lang.NullPointerException.<init>(NullPointerException.java:60)
    at java.lang.String.getBytes(String.java:917)
    at com.intellij.openapi.util.io.FileSystemUtil$JnaUnixMediatorImpl$UnixLibC.lstat(Native Method)
    at com.intellij.openapi.util.io.FileSystemUtil$JnaUnixMediatorImpl.getAttributes(FileSystemUtil.java:460)
    at com.intellij.openapi.util.io.FileSystemUtil.getAttributes(FileSystemUtil.java:116)
    at com.intellij.openapi.vfs.impl.local.LocalFileSystemBase.getAttributes(LocalFileSystemBase.java:769)
    at com.intellij.openapi.vfs.impl.local.LocalFileSystemBase.isDirectory(LocalFileSystemBase.java:107)
    at com.intellij.openapi.vfs.newvfs.impl.VirtualDirectoryImpl.findChild(VirtualDirectoryImpl.java:102)
    at com.intellij.openapi.vfs.newvfs.impl.VirtualDirectoryImpl.refreshAndFindChild(VirtualDirectoryImpl.java:284)
    at com.intellij.openapi.vfs.newvfs.VfsImplUtil.refreshAndFindFileByPath(VfsImplUtil.java:131)
    at com.intellij.openapi.vfs.impl.local.LocalFileSystemBase.refreshAndFindFileByPath(LocalFileSystemBase.java:56)
    at com.intellij.openapi.vfs.impl.local.LocalFileSystemBase.refreshAndFindFileByIoFile(LocalFileSystemBase.java:211)
    at...
```

The full stacktrace: [Stacktrace Error](https://ghostbin.com/paste/enkbq)